# Understanding Khatri-Rao Product

Tags: matrices, vectors, tensor-products, tensors

I am trying to understand in which case one can take Khatri-Rao product.

Suppose there are two matrices $S$ and $Z$ of dimension $K \times N$ and $T \times N$ respectively, then I know that we can take Khatri-Rao product of matrices $S$ and $Z$ and the dimension will be $T K \times N$.

My query is that can we take Khatri-Rao product between matrices $S$ and $Z$ if dimension of $S$ remains same but dimension of $Z$ changes to $N \times T$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.